My program for calculating the integral using the trapezoidal rule with OpenMP + MPI hybrid does not run faster with more threads
As indicated in the title, I have a program which I run on Linux. My question is: why do I get such similar outputs for 1 or 2 processes with different numbers of threads? Shouldn't it be faster with more threads per process? This rule applies for the number of processes greater than 2. Why is that? I need someone who will explain it to me :(
For those who don't know what is going on: I start by calculating the integral over a range <a, b>, setting the number of intervals to be calculated at 100 million. I distribute fragments of these 100 million intervals to each process. Each process then calculates a partial sum of the area under the curve (using reduction with OpenMP) and returns this partial sum to the main process, which combines everything.



Processes
Threads
Intervals_per_process
Trial1 [s]
Trial2 [s]
Trial3 [s]
Average [seconds]




1
1
100000000
79.458205
79.849332
79.784676
79.69740433


1
2
100000000
79.659298
79.555543
80.400979
79.87194


1
3
100000000
79.559082
79.537585
79.535942
79.544203


1
4
100000000
79.594008
79.583018
80.673965
79.95033033


2
1
50000000
42.891658
42.379804
42.370149
42.54720367


2
2
50000000
42.447902
42.487963
42.405998
42.44728767


2
3
50000000
42.436457
42.454243
42.431626
42.44077533


2
4
50000000
42.58225
42.536839
42.526669
42.548586


3
1
33333333
28.78676
34.490129
32.66588
31.980923


3
2
33333333
17.099719
17.314803
16.132476
16.84899933


3
3
33333333
11.878988
11.475592
11.678058
11.677546


3
4
33333333
9.27199
9.091445
8.958381
9.107272


4
1
25000000
23.395599
25.80253
22.365489
23.85453933


4
2
25000000
13.048262
12.91933
12.891229
12.95294033


4
3
25000000
9.064296
9.14309
9.300431
9.169272


4
4
25000000
7.121319
7.088155
7.060605
7.090026333



commands to compile / run (in this case 4 MPI process / 8 OpenMP threads )
mpicc -fopenmp -o example example.c -lm
mpirun -np 4 ./example 8

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include "mpi.h"

long double function(long double x) {
   return 0.1 * pow(x, 50) - 0.2 * pow(x, 48) + 0.3 * pow(x, 47) - 0.4 * pow(x, 45) +
           0.5 * pow(x, 43) - 0.1 * pow(x, 42) + 0.2 * pow(x, 40) - 0.3 * pow(x, 38) +
           0.4 * pow(x, 37) - 0.5 * pow(x, 35) + 0.3 * pow(x, 33) - 0.2 * pow(x, 32) +
           0.1 * pow(x, 30) - 0.2 * pow(x, 28) + 0.3 * pow(x, 27) - 0.1 * pow(x, 25) +
           0.2 * pow(x, 23) - 0.3 * pow(x, 22) + 0.1 * pow(x, 20) + log(pow(x, 2) + 1) + 1;
}

long double trapezoidal_method(long double local_a, long double local_b, int num_intervals, int num_threads) {
    
    omp_set_num_threads(num_threads);

    long double h = (local_b - local_a) / (double)num_intervals;
    long double total_sum = 0;

    long double global_b = local_b;

    #pragma omp parallel shared(total_sum)
    {
        #pragma omp for reduction(+:total_sum)
        
        for (int i = 1; i < num_intervals; i++) {
            long double a = local_a + (i - 1) * h;
            long double b = local_a + i * h;

            total_sum +=  0.5 * (function(a) + function(b)) * h;
        }
        
    }
    //printf("%Lf \n",total_sum);
    return total_sum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    long double partial_sum, global_sum;

    long double parameters[3];

    double start_time, end_time;

    long double interval_start = -1;
    long double interval_end = 1;
    int num_intervals = 100000000;

    int num_threads = atoi(argv[1]);

    int intervals_per_process = (int) floor(num_intervals / size);

    long double step_per_process = (interval_end - interval_start) / size;

    start_time = omp_get_wtime();

    if (rank == 0) {
        partial_sum = 0;

        long double a = interval_start;
        long double b = interval_start + step_per_process;

        int intervals_left = num_intervals;

        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            long double parameters[3] = {a, b, intervals_per_process};

            MPI_Send(parameters, 3, MPI_LONG_DOUBLE , i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            a = b;
            b += step_per_process;
            intervals_left -= intervals_per_process;
        }

        partial_sum = trapezoidal_method(a, interval_end, intervals_left, num_threads);
    } else {
        MPI_Recv(&parameters, 3, MPI_LONG_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        partial_sum = trapezoidal_method(parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], num_threads);
    }

    MPI_Reduce(&partial_sum, &global_sum, 1, MPI_LONG_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    end_time = omp_get_wtime();

    if (rank == 0) {   
        printf("Processes: %d | Threads: %d | Intervals per process: %d | Sum: %Lf | Execution time: %f s. \n", size, num_threads, intervals_per_process, global_sum, end_time - start_time);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}



@EricPostpischil I want my code to run for as long as possible, hence the inefficient use of the pow function. The entire program runs sequentially for a very long time, making it easier to see the improvements when optimized.

@EricPostpischil Yeah, exactly. It's just a university assignment, and I have no clue why it doesn't follow the schema: more threads = bigger speed up (to some extent).

MPI+OpenMP is a two steps tango: first pin the MPI tasks, and then the OpenMP threads. If a MPI task is pinned on a single core, then the OpenMP will end up time sharing, which means no performance improvement when increasing the number of threads. I guess you are using Open MPI, and the default is to pin a MPI task to a NUMA domain when running 3 MPI tasks or more, and pin to a single core with 1 and 2 MPI tasks. try mpirun --bind-to none ... and see how it goes. for a single mpi task, you can also run in singleton mode (e.g. ./example 4)

@GillesGouaillardet thx man, you were right, I wasn't aware this issue, now I am, thx
for those who are interested, it's described over there (example docs. for version mpi 4.1)
https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.1/man1/mpirun.1.php

note for optimal performances when a MPI tasks is running n OpenMP threads, you should bind each MPI task to (at least) n cores - most of the time best performance is achieved when cores are on the same socket/numa domain, YMMV though -  and then have the OpenMP runtime bind each thread to a single core.
